# My join command broke after moving it to a cog file and i cant find how to fix it

Tags: discord.py

```py
@commands.command(name="join")
async def join(self, ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = discord.utils.get(self.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because by using `self.voice_clients` you are trying to get channels of the cog not channels of the bot. Try doing this:
In `__init__` define `self.bot` like this:

```py
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
```

And in the command replace:

```py
discord.utils.get(self.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
```

with:

```py
discord.utils.get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
```

Comment: BTW, a much easier way to get the voice client would be `ctx.voice_client`.

Comment: yep that's right but I wanted to stay as close to provided code as possible

Comment: Thank you this worked I'm really glad that stackoverflow exists!